# NetSuite report attachment

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

So when you email a report out of NetSuite and change the sending format to a CSV, the report is sent as an attachment and the name is defaulted to report.csv.

Would there be anyway to, after the Send button is pressed, to interrupt the email and have it change the attached reports name to the name of the report and not just "report"? I am having trouble finding code to point me in the right direction.

Comment: What report you're trying to export? and how?

Comment: So in this instance it was a part of the Income Statement. To get the outcome, you would be on the report, click the email Icon, a second screen opens asking for details about the message, on the message tab you can change the message format to a csv which will add it as an attachment and name the file report.csv

Comment: Seems NetSuite didn't provide an easy way for this. All I can think is create a schedule script and send report by script. In that way you can set any name you want. Just curious why you need such a feature like this?

Comment: I am working with a client that doesn't like their reports being attached as report, they want their customers and employees to know what the document is that they attached.